# Multiline String literal syntax

Tags: language-agnostic

In many languages multiline String literal syntax is

```
"""
Hello
World
"""
```

But why it require a new syntax, why just not to use `"` instead of `"""` ?

Like:

```
"Hello
 World"
```

Comment: Have you _ever_ tried multiline syntax with a single double quote? You know what? It works!

Comment: In which lang? I know it works in Rust

Comment: "Why do language designers feel the need to add different syntax for multi-line strings in several different languages?" is a great example of asking an overly broad question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is primarily to allow nested double quotes:

```
"""
Hello, "World"
"""
```

If `"` was used for multiline strings, then you had to escape nested quotes which is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: But if I don't have nested double quotes? like in Rust https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483365/what-is-the-syntax-for-a-multiline-string-literal#answer-29483453

Comment: @Sodiaan Are triple quotes a problem for you? You don't want to type?

Comment: Than why to have both, why not only triple quotes?

Comment: @Sodiaan Single-line strings are much more frequent

Answer (score 3):

You can simply include formatted code like this:

```
val text = """
    for (c in "foo")
        print(c)
"""
```

or use special chars like `"` without the need to escape. It's very neat when it comes to JSON for example.